# Clustering a feature matrix using sklearn (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, cluster-computing

I have a dataframe of size 9x100 with tf-idf scores of 100 words that exist in documents 0 to 8, the dataframe can be seen here:

[My Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN860.png)

I then convert this dataframe to a matrix X using:
`X= df.values`

I am trying to cluster these 100 words into 50 clusters (where no empty cluster is allowed) using the `sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering` package but I'm really not too sure how to implement this method on my sample set as I still want to keep the word labels from the dataframe in the data output, could any help out?

Comment: Problem settings suggest every data point should be a document with 100 features (the 100 most important words) and it implies that the maximum number of clusters can be 9. would you clarify this a little?

Comment: @meti I don't really understand what you mean?

Comment: As I understood you are going to cluster `Documents` and you have only 9. So there is no way you can assign them into more than 9 clusters. I think what you said above is related to cluster words (features), instead of documents and I believe it's not what you want. Am I getting anything wrong? @IVB_CODING